# Let $f(x)$ be a function defined for all positive real numbers satisfying the conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $f(x)$ be a function defined for all positive real numbers satisfying the conditions $f(x) > 0$ for all $x > 0$ and $f(x - y) = \sqrt{f(xy) + 1}$ for all $x > y > 0$. Determine $f(2009)$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for all positive real numbers $a$, there is a choice of $x$ and $y$ so that $x$ and $y$ are positive, $x-y=1$ and $xy=a$.  Namely, $x=y+1$ and, by substitution,

$$y^2+y-a=0.$$

The positive solution to this is

$$\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2}.$$

Notice that the numerator is always positive since $1+4a>1$.  Therefore, for all $a$, $f(1)=\sqrt{f(a)+1}$.  In particular, this is true when $a=1$.  In this case, you have

$$f(1)=\sqrt{f(1)+1}.$$

By squaring and moving everything to one side, you have

$$f(1)^2-f(1)-1=0.$$

The only positive number that satisfies this equation is the golden ratio: $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.  In fact, $f$ is the constant function equal to the golden ratio.

Answer (score 0):

There exist two positive real numbers such that $x - y = 2009$ and $xy = 2009.$ Although we do not need to, we can find these numbers:
\begin{align*}
y &= \frac{2009}{x} \\
\Rightarrow \quad x - \frac{2009}{x} &= 2009 \\
\Rightarrow \quad x^2 - 2009x - 2009 &= 0,
\end{align*}or $x = \frac{2009 + \sqrt{2009 \cdot 2013}}{2}, y = \frac{-2009 + \sqrt{2009 \cdot 2013}}{2}$.

In any case, we have $f(2009) = \sqrt{f(2009) + 1}$. Let $r = f(2009).$ Then
\begin{align*}
r &= \sqrt{r + 1} \\
\Rightarrow \quad r^2 &= r + 1 \\
\Rightarrow \quad r^2 - r - 1 &= 0.
\end{align*}
Since we're given $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$, $f(2009)$ is the positive root of the above quadratic. Thus, $f(2009) = \boxed{ \frac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2} },$ the golden ratio.